# jQuery extend object with Prototype object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to aggregate a **Prototype** object to a **JavaScript** normal object:

```
var ModuleA = function( data ) {
    this.data = data;
};

ModuleA.prototype.funcA = function() {
    alert( JSON.stringify( this ) );
}

var myMainObject = { 
    list: []
};

$.extend( myMainObj <--------- ???ect, new ModuleA( 'Haha' ) );

myMainObject.funcA();
```

Now the `myMainObject` will have data property and `funcA` function, since I merge to the `myMainObject`.

When I execute `myMainObject.funcA`, the this arguments actually is `myMainObject`!

To my understanding, when new a **Prototype** object, the function will bind to the object created with the new and pass to the constructor.

But with the **jQuery** extend, the this arguments is not the new object, but point to the `myMainObject`, which confuse me.

Is there any idea?

Comment: You can try it here, http://jsfiddle.net/5oyqq6qa/

Comment: My actual intention is to let ModuleA functions has its own scope without jumble up with the myMainObject attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I execute myMainObject.funcA, the this arguments actually is myMainObject !!!

Right. That's how `this` works in JavaScript. This expression:

```
myMainObject.funcA();
```

looks up the `funcA` property on `myMainObject`, getting back a function reference, and then calls that function, setting `this` during the call to the object that it got the function from (`myMainObject`). That's the normal way `this` is assigned.

If you want `this` to be something else, you can use `Function#bind` to create a function with `this` baked into it, or `Function#call` or `Function#apply` to call a function using a specific `this` value, but **you probably don't want to** in your scenario.

More about `this` *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) *(I need to update this to talk about ES6 arrow functions)*

---

Re your comment:

> My actual intention is to let ModuleA functions has its own scope without jumble up with the myMainObject attribute

Then don't jumble `ModuleA` into `myMainObject`. Sounds like you want *composition* instead:

```
var myMainObject = { 
    list: [],
    moda: new ModuleA()
};

myMainObject.moda.funcA();
```

Comment: Wow, i did not know that javascript did it differently from bind function

Comment: Ya, composition is another way. My scenario is to have my object inherit from PublishSubscribe object which will have the function to subscribe and dispatch Event to all subscriber. composition require client code to know where to find the function, which not so right.

Answer (score 0):

`$.extend` doesn't call constructors, it just copies the data of the object. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

> Properties that are an object constructed via new MyCustomObject(args), or built-in JavaScript types such as Date or RegExp, are not re-constructed and will appear as plain Objects in the resulting object or array.
>
> For needs that fall outside of this behavior, write a custom extend method instead, or use a library like [lodash](http://lodash.com/).